How to handle invalid type in std::stringstream?
I have a code
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    stringstream ss("123 ab 4");
    int a, b, c;
    ss >> a;
    ss >> b;
    ss >> c;

    cout << "XXX_ " << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c <<  endl; // XXX_ 123 0 796488289
}

Why variable b is 0? Is there a rule of handling invalid type in stringstream (e.g. value is "ab" but type is int)?

You need to check whether or not the stream is in a valid state: if (ss) std::cout << ...

Variable b is set to 0 in that case. This is done by the extraction operator>>. If the input fails, the argument to operator>> is set to a default value. For an int it's 0.

Check this out. All stream classes are similar. How to validate bad input from a file stream?

@user4581301 c remains in an unspecified state since it's not initialized. The stream fails upon reading "ab" and stops the extraction process. Thus c keeps its garbage value. It's not overwritten by operator<<.

@digito_evo Ja. I reread the Standard section on what happens after commenting to see if I'd missed a gotcha. c's never touched because of insta-fail of reading from a failed stream.

In order to test whether the conversion was successful, you should test whether the stream is in a failed state, for example by calling std::basic_ios::operator bool (which is a function in a base class of std::stringstream). Here is an example:
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss( "123 ab 4" );
    int a, b, c;

    ss >> a;
    ss >> b;
    ss >> c;

    if ( ss )
    {
        std::cout << "Conversion successful:\n";
        std::cout << a << '\n' << b << '\n' << c << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Conversion failure!\n";
    }
}

This program has the following output:
Conversion failure!

You can also test the stream state after every single conversion operation, for example like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss( "123 456 ab 4" );

    for (;;)
    {
        int i;

        ss >> i;

        if ( !ss )
            break;
        
        std::cout << "Successfully converted: " << i << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "Unable to convert any more numbers.";
}

This program has the following output:
Successfully converted: 123
Successfully converted: 456
Unable to convert any more numbers.


More colloquially,  if (ss >> a >> b >> c) { /* success case */ } else { /* fail case */ } Not so useful here, but very, very handy in a loop.

ss >> a >> b >> c; is even better (in this case). But extracting one value at a time is useful when we need to check the state of the input operation at each step.

@digito_evo: I have now added an example of extracting one value at a time.

Though you can test the stream afterwords. I definately think it is easier to test the operation:  if (ss >> i) { /* Input Success */ } I also think this is easier to read.
